# Python Multiprocessing slower than sequential

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I have been playing around with the multiprocessing API and can't figure out why my code runs slower when I use the ProcessPoolExecutor on CPU bound code. For some reason, multithreading is much faster than multiprocessing, even though the code isn't I/O bound, although sequential remains the fastest.

I need to loop over a list of different elements (trades) and iterate over 3 other lists (list_ois_curves_directional, list_dual_curves_directional, list_basis_curves_directional). To accomplish this, I use executor.map inside a for loop. Is there a better way to program this? Any feedback would be appreciated, I've been struggling for some time.
Thanks

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
def risks_parallel(trade, list_ois_curves_directional, list_dual_curves_directional, list_basis_curves_directional):

MtM_result = pricer_engine(trade[0], trade[1], trade[2], trade[3], trade[4], trade[5], trade[6], trade[7], list_dual_curves_directional, list_ois_curves_directional, trade[10], trade[11], trade[12])
return MtM_result

def executor_function(trades):
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:

        for trade in trades:

            # Run the risks in parallel for each trade
            results = executor.map(risks_parallel, repeat(trade), list_ois_curves_directional, list_dual_curves_directional, list_basis_curves_directional)

return
```

Comment: `multiprocessing` has extreme levels of inter-process communication overhead.

Comment: There is a large overhead for starting and terminating threads and for IPC, even more for multiple processes.  This is the reason for your slow down.  To get better results, try to increase the amount of work each thread does.  You may want to try to make your `for trade in trades` loop parallel for example

Comment: Starting processes is heavyweight- even heavier is that data passed back and forth has to be serialized/deserialized. If your algorithm is already as efficient as possible, your options are to minimize comms/processes (start fixed number of process, pass a pointer to data instead of the data, stuff like that), use a library like numpy that is written in c to bypass the GIL, or write your own C extension to bypass the GIL.